# Cannot call an Anonymous Class Method

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I'm trying to call a method, `setPostal(String post)` I made from an anonymous class, but for some reason the compiler doesnt even recognize it in main. Any reason why this is? Part of my code (address is an inner class of Student):

### Student

```
public class Student implements Gradeable, Cloneable {
    String name;
    int id;
    Address address;

    public Student() {
        name = "unknown";
        address = new Address();
    }

    public Student(String name, int id, Integer... option) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        if (option.length > 0) {
            if (option[0] > 0) {
                address = new Address() {
                    String postal;

                    public void setPostal(String post) {
                        postal = post;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        return "Street: " + street + " | number: " + number
                                + " | town: " + town + " | province: " + province
                                + " | Postal Code: " + postal;
                    }
                };
            }
        } else {
            address = new Address();
        }
    }

    Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException, InterruptedException {
        Student test = new Student("ryan", 41254, 1);
        test.getAddress().setPostal("L1G 6h9") // Compiler: Cannot resolve symbol 'setPostal'
    }
}
```

### Address

```
public class Address implements Cloneable {
    String street;
    int number;
    String town;
    String province;
    String zip;

    public Address() {

    }

    public Address(String street, int number, String town,
                   String province, String zip) {
        this.street = street;
        this.number = number;
        this.town = town;
        this.province = province;
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Street: " + street + " | number: " + number
                + " | town: " + town + " | province: " + province
                + " | ZIP: " + zip;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Address)
            if (((Address) obj).getStreet().equals(street)
                    && ((Address) obj).getNumber() == number
                    && ((Address) obj).getTown().equals(town)
                    && ((Address) obj).getProvince().equals(province)
                    && ((Address) obj).getZip().equals(zip)){
                System.out.println("Address equal");
                return true;
            }
        System.out.println("Address not equal");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your `Address` class, or at least an interface for it, which includes `setPostal(String):void`.

Comment: Can you show the `Address` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [call anonymous class method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381094/call-anonymous-class-method-in-java)

Comment: Is `Address` nested inside `Student`? Please fix your code. Also, why is `Address` not `public`? I moved `Address` out of `Student`, looks like you just pasted it wherever.

Comment: Yes, it's the inner class of Student. I stated it in the OP. My mistake if it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, whatever `Address` is, it doesn't have a `setPostal(String)` method.

Instance methods, at compile time, are resolved based on the type of the value on which they are invoked.

You're invoking it

```
test3.getAddress().setPostal("L1G 6h9") //Compiler: Cannot resolve symbol 'setPostal'
```

on an expression of type `Address`, which doesn't have such a method, regardless of the fact that a subtype (the anonymous subclass) does.

---

The only way (minus reflection) to invoke a method that is declared only in an anonymous class is to invoke the method on the value returned by the anonymous class instance creation expression.

```
new Address() {
    String postal;
    public void setPostal(String post) {
        postal = post;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Street: " + street + " | number: " + number
                        + " | town: " + town + " | province: " + province
                        + " | Postal Code: " + postal;
        }
    }
}.setPostal("whatever");
```

Comment: I really don't get if `test3` instance not present how can we call method on that? please can you assist me

Comment: @atish It might be a typo. It might just not be shown. Either way, they would get a completely different error.

Comment: ya, that's my mistake. Im only posting part of my code, so I accidentally erased the instantiation of test3. I changed test3 to test so that it makes sense now.

Comment: You could also return `this` from the `setPostal()` if you wanted to chain multiple.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the expression `test3.getAddress()` is `Address`, which means you can only call methods that are declared in the `Address` class (or a supertype of it).

The compiler doesn't figure out that at run time, this expression is going to evaluate to be an object of your special anonymous class.  It's not the compiler's job to run your program for you, so it can work out the class of every object you might use.  So the new method `setPostal` (which appears to only exist in your anonymous class) can't be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous classes are a bad idea. Try to create a concrete class, then instantiate that.

You can declare this inside your class to hide it from the outside.

```
public class Student implements Gradeable, Cloneable {
    // ...
    private static class PostalAddress extends Address {
        String postal;

        public PostalAddress {
            super();
        }        

        public void setPostal(String post) {
            postal = post;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Street: " + street + " | number: " + number
                + " | town: " + town + " | province: " + province
                + " | Postal Code: " + postal;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then use it

```
public Student(String name, int id, Integer... option) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    if (option.length > 0) {
        if (option[0] > 0) {
            address = new PostalAddress();
        }
    } else {
        address = new Address();
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is cast the address in `test`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException, InterruptedException{
   Student test = new Student("ryan", 41254, 1);
   ((PostalAddress) test.getAddress()).setPostal("L1G 6h9");
}
```

---

**Note:** if `option.length > 0` but `option[0] <= 0`, your `address` object will be `null`.

Comment: This won't make the slightest bit of difference, because the return type of `getAddress()` is still `Address`, not `PostalAddress`.

Comment: Well, that just means that the architecture of the code will need to be re-thought.

Comment: Maybe.  But the point is, using a named class instead of an anonymous class is not going to fix OP's issue.

Comment: The `Student` call can accept a generic argument which is of type `Address`. `Student<T extends Address>` then set the return type of `getAddress()` to `T`.

Comment: Well this will...  `((PostalAddress)test3.getAddress()).setPostal("L1G 6h9");`

Comment: OK, then _that_ should be in your answer.  Because _that_ would fix OP's problem.  It might even cause me to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

For those getting:

**"Cannot find symbol"** FUNCTION_NAME_HERE.

When trying to use an **anonymous inner class** on the fly:

---

---

**WRONG**: error: cannot find symbol "myMethod"

```
Object t = new Object(){ 
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("[METHOD]");
    };;
};;
t.myMethod();
```

**BECAUSE**:

Though method exists, your anonymous
object is downcasted to Object, which
does NOT have method.

---

**WRONG**: error: cannot find symbol "myMethod"

```
class Test{};
Test t = new Test(){
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("[METHOD]");
    };;
};;
t.myMethod();
```

**BECAUSE:**

Same reason as previous.
(But we are on the right track.)

---

---

**CORRECT:**

```
abstract class Test{ abstract public void myMethod(); }
Test t = new Test(){
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("[METHOD]");
    };;
};;
t.myMethod();
```

**Congratulations**:

You've created a class on the fly in which there can only be one instance.

Usage: Small helper functions in a function.